# Search for Header name exactly

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a macro to search for Header name and insert a column, but the macro searches for the words containing what has been given in the command instead of searching the exact Header Name.

```
'Looks in entire first row.
Dim rngHeaders As Range Set rngHeaders = Range("1:1")

'To set this to a specific sheetname, use Set ws = Sheets("Sheetname")
Set ws = ActiveSheetSet 
Set rngUsernameHeader = rngHeaders.Find(What:="Account Name",After:=Cells(1,1))

If rngUsernameHeader Is Nothing Then

Else 
    rngUsernameHeader.Offset(0, 1).EntireColumn.Insert 
endif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a parameter for Find:

```
Dim rngHeaders As Range 

Set rngHeaders = Range("1:1") 
Set ws = ActiveSheetSet 

Set rngUsernameHeader = rngHeaders.Find(What:="Account Name",After:=Cells(1,1), LookAt:=xlWhole)

If Not rngUsernameHeader Is Nothing Then rngUsernameHeader.Offset(0, 1).EntireColumn.Insert
```

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to Find function documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-find-method-excel.

You are looking for LookIn parameter. This parameter should be set to xlValues value which will enable function to search through cells based on their values.